# How to know if a diode is Schottky or power Schottky?

Tags: schottky

I bought a diode for a circuit but the guy who sells components asked me if I want Schottky or power Schottky. I need to buy SB2040 but I cannot figure out what type it is.

Comment: Schottkys with a higher current is usually called rectifiers, not diodes. They guy basically wants to know how much power it will have to handle. SB2040 is a rectifier.

Comment: @Gunnish Every diode is a rectifier, and if you scan through a few datasheets you will notice that the distinction is not as black and white as you suggest.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh yes, well, therefore "usually", its more common than the opposite is my experience. Not true in all cases.

Comment: Ask him for an SB2040 - it doesn't matter what "name" it is given.

Comment: user16307 Going by the kind of question the seller is asking, I suspect (a) that you are in India, or some such geography where the sellers actually have no clue what they are selling, (b) you are probably going to be shown whatever Schottky TO220 devices they have in stock, and told that it's all the same, and (c) you are going to be sold old stock, that has not necessarily been stored ESD-safe, and is probably going to fail on you far sooner than normal.

Comment: I would add that for me, the term 'signal' diode is just a small diode, be it smd or through-hole. If it is used to rectify 'power', then it is a power rectifier. Marketing can play all the games they want. The end user calls it what they want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction between a "Schottky Diode" and a "Power Schottky Diode" is notional, essentially **marketing terminology**.

You would choose your diode depending on the maximum current expected to flow through it in forward bias operation. So just buy whatever can handle your worst-case current and is rated for the desired junction voltage.

Typically, manufacturers indicate high current (1 Amperes and up) Shottky diodes as power Schottky, though IIRC even some 100 mA rated ones have a "Power Schottky" mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, do u think SB2040 is Schottky or power Schottky?

Comment: @user16307 As it is in a TO220 package, vendors would consider it a "power Schottky".

Answer (score 1):

## Is your device a power device?

As a general rule you have a tradeoff. Making the junction bigger reduces forward voltage at a given forward current and allows a higher maximum forward current without destroying the device but it comes at a price of more silicon area, more capacitance and more reverse leakage.

"signal" devices will be fairly small to keep capacitance and reverse leakage down whole power devices will be much bigger to allow operation at high currents.

The exact line is somewhat fuzzy and some devices can be used in both signal and power applications but your device falls squarely on the "power" side of the line. The [specs in the datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/34082/WTE/SB2040CT.html) are given at currents orders of magnitude higher than would be seen in signal applictions.

---

## Why does your supplier want you to anser to the above question

This is the bit that concerns me because it's the wrong question to be asking.

A vendor who intends to supply the exact part specified really wouldn't need to ask a question like this. A vendor who intends to propose a substitute and is competant to do so would be asking for actual requirements, not wooly marketing crap.

So I strongly suspect that your vendor intends to propose a substitute but is not competant to do so correctly.